# Mixed effect and learning curves?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, fitting

My question might be too simple but I just started to do statistical analysis and use R and is not always simple!

I have performance data for 5 subjects with different level of experience, repeating the same task 6 times. I would like to predict the time to perform the task with mixed effect models. I have been building a model including the time as a response, the Trial number, the previous experience and their interaction as fixed effects and the subjects as random effects. Would this be correct? I have been then showing the learning pattern plotting my data and adding a smooth line (lowess).

This is the first model

```
> ma <- lme(prod.time~Trial+Previous.experience+Trial*Previous.experience, 
            data=  Data27_04, random=~1|Student, method="ML")
> summary(ma)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
Data: Data27_04 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1517.445 1541.259 -750.7226

Random effects:
Formula: ~1 | Student
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    7.337648 42.42332

Fixed effects: prod.time ~ Trial + Previous.experience + Trial * Previous.experience 
                               Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)                102.44173  9.561987 137 10.713435  0.0000
Trial                       -6.48494  2.252271 137 -2.879291  0.0046
Previous.experience1       -37.36173 14.786033   2 -2.526826  0.1274
Previous.experience2        47.22627 12.451072   2  3.792948  0.0630
Trial:Previous.experience1   6.55351  3.496401 137  1.874360  0.0630
Trial:Previous.experience2  -7.55163  2.940879 137 -2.567813  0.0113
Correlation: 
                           (Intr) Trial  Prvs.1 Prvs.2 Tr:P.1
Trial                      -0.841                            
Previous.experience1        0.253 -0.208                     
Previous.experience2       -0.234  0.199 -0.540              
Trial:Previous.experience1 -0.207  0.264 -0.835  0.447       
Trial:Previous.experience2  0.199 -0.226  0.447 -0.836 -0.550

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.3519731 -0.6903211 -0.1031114  0.6503216  4.6699702 

Number of Observations: 145
Number of Groups: 5 
>
```

Do you think this is good enough to demonstrate a learning effect?

Learning curves are exponential. I have been trying to log transform the response variable but then p-values are saying that previous experience has no significance.

```
>  mb<-lme(log.prodtime~Trial+Previous.experience+Trial*Previous.experience, 
           data=  Data27_04, random=~1|Student, method="ML")
> summary(mb)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
Data: Data27_04 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  225.1042 248.9181 -104.5521

Random effects:
Formula: ~1 | Student
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:  0.04484554 0.495812

Fixed effects: log.prodtime ~ Trial + Previous.experience + Trial * Previous.experience 
                               Value  Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)                 4.448206 0.10593072 137 41.99165  0.0000
Trial                      -0.060150 0.02629765 137 -2.28726  0.0237
Previous.experience1       -0.333664 0.16351518   2 -2.04057  0.1781
Previous.experience2        0.368358 0.13776525   2  2.67381  0.1160
Trial:Previous.experience1  0.051714 0.04084708 137  1.26604  0.2076
Trial:Previous.experience2 -0.043036 0.03435150 137 -1.25282  0.2124
Correlation: 
                           (Intr) Trial  Prvs.1 Prvs.2 Tr:P.1
Trial                      -0.886                            
Previous.experience1        0.248 -0.221                     
Previous.experience2       -0.237  0.209 -0.535              
Trial:Previous.experience1 -0.220  0.266 -0.881  0.473       
Trial:Previous.experience2  0.208 -0.225  0.474 -0.883 -0.551

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.7119095 -0.8005032  0.1127388  0.8621127  2.1988560 

Number of Observations: 145
Number of Groups: 5 
>
```

The model is surely better (AIC, BIC) also the residuals are looking better but then should I reduce the model leaving only the Trial number?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to compare models with different response variables using $AIC$ or $BIC$. Since you log-transformed the response for the second model, it is on a different scale than the untransformed variable in the first model.

Whether a variable should be log-transformed depends on the theory and on the distribution of the model's residuals.

The residuals should be normally distributed. For the model fits `ma` and `mb`  you can check this using

```
qqnorm(residuals(ma))
qqnorm(residuals(mb))
```

Deviations from a straight line indicate non-normally distributed residuals.

Furthermore, you could plot residuals against fitted values to check homogeneity:

```
plot(fitted(ma), residuals(ma))
plot(fitted(ma), residuals(ma))
```

The distribution of the residuals should not change with the fitted values.

Comment: Thanks Sven, I have been checking the residuals of course and i have been also testing my full model against a "null" model with only random effect using ANOVA. My qyestion is whether the first model could be correct to interpret my experiment. The difference in the residual distribution is not that much. I think that even is a learning curve is exponential the fact that I have so little repetitions assimilates it to a line.